# Meshlab 202.02 does not start

Tags: meshlab

Ive just installed meshlab 2020.02 on my computer :
[system specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVPZI.png)
But when I try to run the program is see a quick flash of a window and then nothing. I have installed the latest nvidia driver, but that does not help. 
I've read on some forums that I can enable running with nVidia in the nVidia control panel, but I cannot get that open by the means that they propose.

Older versions of meshlab ran perfectly. I also added meshlab to the list "program settings" in the nvidia control panel, but that does not make a difference.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Windows try to uninstall the old version first, then install the newest version.

I hope this helps !